# Clicking confirm dialog using firefox 5 and selenium server 2.2

Tags: selenium, phpunit

the biggest issue i'm having is that when i click on a link, i can see the confirmation dialog popup. from this site it says:

NOTE: under Selenium, JavaScript confirmations will NOT pop up a visible dialog.

NOTE: Selenium does NOT support JavaScript confirmations that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until you manually click OK.

any idea why i'm seeing a popup when i shouldn't be, or how i can click the 'Ok' on it?

edit: when i record the test using the selenium IDE and run it, it handles confirmation boxes fine. when i exported that test case to PHP, it doesn't work. this is without modifying the code -- using purely what was provided by the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call
`chooseOkOnNextConfirmation()` function

From http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html